# Include HTML tags in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file and I'd like to include a couple of HTML tags.  Mainly  to help the content display nicely.

The JSON is populating a select field and the attribute I want amending is the "name".

I've looked and found some info on here such as using `{"html": "<p>I'm the markup</p>"}` that someone else posted as an answer but I can't use this.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so could you help?  Thanks.

Snippet of the JSON file:

```
"area" :    [ 
    {
        "value":"sqCentimetres",
        "name":"Square Centimetre (cm<sup>2</sup>)"
    },
    {
        "value":"sqYard",
        "name":"Square Yard"
    }],
```

when outputted the tags are not visible.  it just simply reads (cm2)

EDITED TO PROVIDE OUTPUT INFO:

```
     <script>
//        JSON:
//        The key is the class identifier, temp, area etc etc
//        Value is being used for both ID and Value when the list is being populated
        $.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){

            console.log(data);
            //for testing output only
            var list = $("<ul />");

            $.each(data, function (key, conversions) {
                console.log(key + ":" + conversions);

                $.each(conversions, function (index, conversion) {
                    console.log("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>");

                    if(key == "<?php echo $conversionType ?>"){

                        $("#from").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                        $("#to").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                        //testing output
                        var elem = $("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>").appendTo(list);
                    }
                });
            });
            //$("#testJSON").html(list);
        });

    </script>
```

and an example of the form:

```
<div class="ourContactFormElementSelect">
        <label for="from">Convert From:</label>
            <select size = "10" name="from" id="from" onchange="convertUnits()">
                <option value="from">-Select an Option-</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are they in the source?

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PdvCm/

Comment: What are you doing with the JSON?

Comment: outputted how? [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode), `alert`, `console.log`, setting value of an input?

Comment: It completely depends on the way that the field values are added to the page, but have not included that information in your question.

Comment: How are you outputting it?

Comment: works for you?! Odd -.-
Its being read in to auto populate a select list.
  $("#from").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');

Comment: Option tags can not have html in it. That would be your problem. Showing that in your original question would have helped.

Comment: Why the need for all the negatives?

Comment: @SteveGreen: I didn't down-vote, but it was probably because you didn't give enough details.  "when outputted the tags are not visible".  We needed to know where you outputted it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, cheers for the edit.  Have you any idea why it's not working?  THe guys on here are usually really helpful and above was the first experience of someone being a bit of a tit.  I'll make sure to include more info in the initial question next time

Comment: @SteveGreen: It's Monday, maybe people are just grumpy :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yeah maybe :) maybe the head is where sunlight doesn't reach. I think Sumurai has the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<option>` tag cannot contain any html tags ([docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)). You can however include escaped characters. Use `&#178;` instead.